# If $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)<0$, must there exist some $x'\in \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x')<0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Suppose for some $f(x)$,  $\lim_{x\to \infty}  f(x)<0$. Must there exist some $x'\in \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x')<0$ ?

Comment: Consider the constant function.

Comment: Hint: if $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = c < 0$$

there is an $M>0$ such that for all $x>M$ we have $f(x) \in \left[\frac{3}{2}c, \frac{1}{2}c\right]$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, where did you get this from?

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope.

Comment: Will do, thanks!

Comment: @pafnuti  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It descends directly from the definition of limit.

Moreover it exist a value $\bar x$ such that $$f(x)<0 \quad \forall x>\bar x$$

Indeed the definition of finite limit $L$ for $x\to \infty$ is:

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \quad \exists M \quad x \geq M \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$

Now since $L<0$ we can choose for example $$\epsilon <\left|\frac{L}{3}\right|$$

and find $M$ in such way that :

$$-\left|\frac{L}{3}\right|<f(x)-L<\left|\frac{L}{3}\right|$$

$$L-\left|\frac{L}{3}\right|<f(x)<L+\left|\frac{L}{3}\right|<0$$

Thus

> $$\forall \bar x\geq M \implies f(\bar x)<0 $$

Comment: But what if the function is not strictly decreasing, so that $f(x')<0$ but $f(x'')>0$ where $x''>x'$, then, despite the limit, it is not true that $\forall x > \overline{x}$

Comment: The point is that if the limit exists the function approches the limit value as near as you want, thus must exists a value $\bar x$ from which the function remains negative.

Answer (score 1):

**Definition:** $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=c\iff\forall\epsilon\gt0,\exists N:x\ge N\implies|f(x)-c|\le\epsilon$

**Hint:** Choose $\epsilon\lt|c|$.